# How to store List of adb devices on network into php array

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, unix

Running the command:

```
$output = shell_exec("adb devices -l");

echo  "$output";
```

and getting output like this:

```
List of devices attached
10.16.21.138:5555      device product:tbltevzw model:SM_N915V device:tbltevzw
10.16.20.90:5555       device product:ghost_verizon model:XT1060 device:ghost
```

can  some one help to store this information into php associative array?

Answer (score 2):

```
// remove extra spaces, then split into array by new lines
$arr = explode("\n", preg_replace('/  +/',' ',$x));
array_shift($arr); // remove 1-st line
$result = Array();
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $tmp = explode(' ',$v); // split each line into words
    list($ip,$port) = explode(':',$tmp[0]);
    $item = Array('ip'=>$ip, 'port'=>$port);    
    array_shift($tmp); // remove IP:PORT
    array_shift($tmp); // remove DEVICE
    foreach($tmp as $n)
    {
        list($key,$data) = explode(':',$n); // split by :
        $item[$key] = $data; // accumulate key/data pairs
    }
    $result[] = $item; // append device to the result array
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it was helpfull